# With some request Postman hang forever - what to do?

Tags: postman

Working with Postman I found that with some request Postman hang forever : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WY5e.jpg
and wonder if there is a valid way to debug/close this request ?
The only way I found is to close postman manually and run gain...

Thanks!

Comment: what happened when you try the same request in browser or any other rest clients .  Usually it happens if server have some issue and is not sending bac kany response

Comment: browser hardly can be used here - that is POST request with namy fields. Are there some other rest clients can be tested/used with Postman ?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/